# Reduce pairs - python

Tags: python, mapreduce, apache-spark, pyspark

If i had to reduce over a pair of values, how do i write the lambda expression for the same.

```
testr =  [('r1', (1, 1)), ('r1', (1, 5)),('r2', (1, 1)),('r3', (1, 1))]
```

Desired output is

```
('r1', (2, 6)),('r2', (1, 1)),('r3', (1, 1))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduce it by Key:

```
.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: (a[0]+b[0], a[1]+b[1]))
```

You can make it more general purpose for arbitrary length tuples with zip:

```
.reduceByKey(lambda a, b: tuple(x+y for x,y in zip(a,b)))
```

Comment: i will try this. I have strings as keys and the value pair always contains integer values

Comment: Your data shows a mix in the value pairs, you can eliminate the `int()` calls if they are all ints.

Answer (score 0):

```
it is not clear for me how reduce can use to reduce with lambda to reduce list tuples with different keys. My solution is can reduce list of tuples, but it uses function, which is perhaps too troublesome to do in pure lambda, if not impossible.

def reduce_tuple_list(tl):

    import operator as op
    import functools as fun
    import itertools as it

    # sort the list for groupby
    tl = sorted(tl,key=op.itemgetter(0))
    # this function with reduce lists with the same key
    def reduce_with_same_key(tl):
        def add_tuple(t1,t2):
            k1, tl1 = t1
            k2, tl2 = t2
            if k1 == k2:
                l1,r1 = tl1
                l2,r2 = tl2
                l = l1+l2
                r = r1+r2
                return  k1,(l,r)
            else:
                return t1,t2
        return tuple(fun.reduce(add_tuple, tl))

    # group by keys
    groups = []
    for k, g in it.groupby(tl, key=op.itemgetter(0)):
        groups.append(list(g))

    new_list = []
    # we need to add only lists whose length is greater than one
    for el in groups:
        if len(el) > 1: # reduce
            new_list.append(reduce_with_same_key(el))
        else: # single tuple without another one with the same key
            new_list.append(el[0])
    return new_list


    testr =  [('r1', (1, 1)), ('r3', (11, 71)), ('r1', (1, 5)),('r2', (1, 1)),('r3', (1, 1))]

    >>> reduce_tuple_list(testr)

    [('r1', (2, 6)), ('r2', (1, 1)), ('r3', (12, 72))]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use combineByKey method

```
testr =  sc.parallelize((('r1', (1, 1)), ('r1', (1, 5)),('r2', (1, 1)),('r3', (1, 1))))

testr.combineByKey(lambda x:x,lambda x,y:(x[0]+y[0],x[1]+y[1]),lambda x,y:(x[0]+x[1],y[0]+y[1])).collect()
```